# ScrollView doesn't want to show up with Image

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, scrollview

I'm wondering all the time why the scrollView dosen't want to show up. I'm downloading some image from the Internet and then setting it as a Drawable in a ImageView but nothing happens. When picture is small everything works fine. Where is the mistake?

Funkction where I'm populating View:

```
public void setUpLayout()
    {

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        heightOfScreen = height;

        heighOfImage = image.getHeight();

        System.out.println("Screen" +height);
        System.out.println("IMAGE" + heighOfImage);

        if(heighOfImage < height)
        {
            imageViewSmall.setImageBitmap(image);
            imageViewSmall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            scrollViewImage.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {

            scrollViewImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageViewBig.setImageBitmap(image);
            //imageViewBig.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            scrollViewImage.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

And XML file with all content View:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:gesture-image="http://schemas.polites.com/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textB"
        android:text="dadasadsadsasddassdsdsdsadasdd"/>

    <com.polites.android.GestureImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageSmal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below ="@+id/textB"
           android:visibility="gone"

           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            gesture-image:max-scale="10.0"
            gesture-image:min-scale="0.0"
            gesture-image:strict="false" />

   <ScrollView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSmal"

        android:id="@+id/scrollViewImage"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone">


       <com.polites.android.GestureImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageBig"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            gesture-image:max-scale="10.0"
            gesture-image:min-scale="0.0"
            gesture-image:strict="false" />

    </ScrollView>

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/imageProgressBar"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"

       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tested the visibility setting of the ImageView you want to show up?

Comment: Yes, in XML file and also in a code and it is still no showing up

Comment: why you do not use listview?